# Replacing emoticon text with images using CSS

Tags: javascript, css

I was wondering if there is a method for replacing text with a span object using purely CSS?

For example:

```
This is a :) sample text
```

The :) in above example would be replaced by

```
This is a <span class="emot-smile"></span> sample text
```

or something similar that hides the text itself and adds the span.

Is :before and :after selectors something I could use?

Comment: Not really, because CSS can't reach individual text fragments, let alone parts of text fragments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's not possible in pure CSS.

CSS is for styling. For dynamic changes of content on the page you have to use Javascript. 
For this smile:

```
var str = "This is a :) sample text";
str = str.replace(":)", "<span class='emot-smile'>replaced span</span>");

document.write( str );​
```

Comment: `alert("String with :)".replace(':)', '<span class="smiley"></span>'));`

Comment: Or you could do this server-side.

Answer (score 1):

No. CSS can not wrap your content and modify DOM tree.